# get complete content of two web Database Tables

Tags: sql, database, cordova

I need to get the complete content of a column of two tables in a phonegap Database
I try it like this now:

```
db.transaction(function(tx){
               tx.executeSql('SELECT Table1.iTicketName, Table2.iTicketName FROM Table1, Table2', [],function (tx, results){
                 console.log("Callback from Database");
                 var len = results.rows.length;
                 for (var i=0;i<len;i++){
                         var ticketname = results.rows.item(i);
                             console.log(ticketname);

                    }  

                 },
                 errorCB, 
                 successCB
              )
   })
```

But I only get the content of Table1. I dont know how to send the correct Query and I googled a lot now. All I found was Joins but I need to get the complete content of the table.
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a UNION query:

```
SELECT Table1.iTicketName FROM Table1
UNION ALL 
SELECT Table2.iTicketName FROM Table2
```

The "ALL" part is there if you don't want to suppress duplicates

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT iTicketName FROM Table1
union
SELECT iTicketName FROM Table2
```